# Can you create a clickable button to jump to a cell in a column in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet document for reporting my campaigns structured in the following way:

- Column A with the dates (entered for the next six months).
- Column B where I must enter the income from my campaigns

Each day, I put data in column B.

I've been entering my results every day for several months.

Now when I want to enter data in column B, I need to scroll to find the right line in column A that corresponds to today's date.

Is it possible to create a clickable button in a Google Sheet that can automatically scroll (=jump) to show me the line in column A with today's date? Do I need to use Apps Script to make it?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to avoid Apps Script you can do it with formula, with HYPERLINK:

```
=HYPERLINK("PUT HERE THE LINK OF YOUR SPREADSHEET OPEN IN THE TAB YOU WISH/range=A"&XMATCH(TODAY(),A:A),"Today's date")
```

For example:

```
=HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lONet9RyQwKpURnmzlYcrH7kgssZjGrQyiG-fh6J7gg/edit#gid=736201905/range=A"&XMATCH(TODAY(),A:A),"Today's date")
```

You'd get a result like this, that is clickable to the cell matching with today's date:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const sr = 2;//datastart row
  const vs = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1).getValues().flat();
  const dt = new Date();
  const dtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf();
  for(let i = 0;i< vs.length;i++) {
    let d = new Date(vs[i]);
    let dv = new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf();
    if(dtv == dv) {
      sh.getRange(i + sr, 1).activate();
      break;
    }
   }
  }
```

- [Date.valueOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf)
- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)